# Android Custom Keyboard changing from Activity

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have made an Custom Keyboard app:

```
public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener
{
    private KeyboardView kv;
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    private boolean caps = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView()
    {
        kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/keyboard"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:keyBackground="@drawable/key_image"
android:background="@drawable/keyboard_image"
android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"
/>
```

Now, there is a settings key, and when user presses it, new *Activity* opens. This *Activity* has two buttons. First one should change keyboards background image, and the second one should change button background image.

I was trying some things, but I can't manage to do it. Can someone please tell me how should I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: setBackground should work for the kb background, I don't think there is a function for the keys.  Really when you want to get beyond the absolute basics, you need to leave KeyboardView behind and write a custom view.  It just isn't very flexible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. It is easy to change the keyboard by changing its theme from activity:

```
themePreferencesEditor.putInt(THEME_KEY, 2);
themePreferencesEditor.commit();
```

And then in IME:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateInputView()
    {
        pre = getSharedPreferences("CUSTOM_KEYBOARD_PREFERENCES", 1);
        theme = pre.getInt(THEME_KEY, 1);
        switch (theme)
        {
            case 1:
                kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
                break;
            case 2:
                kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard1, null);
                break;
            case 3:
                kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard2, null);
                break;
            case 4:
                kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard3, null);
                break;
            case 5:
                kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard4, null);
                break;
            case 6:
                kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard5, null);
                break;
            default:
                kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
                break;
        }
        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
        return kv;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartInputView(EditorInfo info, boolean restarting)
    {
        super.onStartInputView(info, restarting);
        setInputView(onCreateInputView());
    }
```